# Android Studio - Sync Project With Gradle files

Tags: android-studio

Sync Project With Gradle files option in android studio is disabled for my android studio project, how can i enable this.?

Comment: I also wish to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

I just got this problem and got the "Sync Project with Gradle files" re-enabled after I detach the Gradle link and then re-open the project.

To detach Gradle link:

- Open Gradle Windows, from View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle menu,
- Remove the project from that window with the (-) button,
- Close project.
- Reopen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference

Answer (score -1):

Open New->Import Project-> select your project and open it. Hope this will Help